# "On my iPhone" option is not visible in simulator.

Tags: ios, iphone, files-app

While saving files "On My iPhone" option is not visible in simulator. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 : Open Files app in your simulator

2 : Drag any file from your Mac to simulator's files app and select "on My iPhone".

[image: Drag and drop files here and select "on My iPhone"]

Now it'll always show "on My iPhone" option for saving files

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings>notes>on my phone will also let you select it there too. Also, if you go to files there is an edit in the top right if you select browse on the bottom that will allow you to toggle on my phone to on if it is off.